# Каким образом создать несколько сборок с различным кодом на основе одного проекта?

Tags: java, maven, gitlab-ci, непрерывная-интеграция, jna

Имеется библиотека [FOCAS](https://www.inventcom.net/fanuc-focas-library/general/fwlib32) на C от производителя CNC станков FANUC для которой необходимо реализовать [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) обёртку. Проблема заключается в том, что тип данных параметров функций различается в зависимости от модели/серии CNC-машины, к которой выполняется подключение.

Приведу конкретный пример. Имеется функция [cnc_statinfo](https://www.inventcom.net/fanuc-focas-library/misc/cnc_statinfo)

```cpp
FWLIBAPI short WINAPI cnc_statinfo( unsigned short FlibHndl, ODBST* statinfo );
```

где параметром передаётся указатель на структуру ODBST, которая выглядит по разному в зависимости от используемой модели/серии:

```cpp
// Series 15/15i
typedef struct odbst {
     short  dummy[2];
     short  aut;
     short  manual;
     short  run;
     short  edit;
     short  motion;
     short  mstb;
     short  emergency;
     short  write;
     short  labelskip;
     short  alarm;
     short  warning;
     short  battery;
} ODBST;
// Series 16/18/21, 16i/18i/21i, 0i, 30i/31i/32i, Power Mate i, PMi-A
typedef struct odbst {
     short  hdck;
     short  tmmode;
     short  aut;
     short  run;
     short  motion;
     short  mstb;
     short  emergency;
     short  alarm;
     short  edit;
} ODBST;
// Series 16i/18i-W
typedef struct odbst {
     short  dummy[2];
     short  aut;
     short  run;
     short  motion;
     short  mstb;
     short  emergency;
     short  alarm;
     short  edit;
} ODBST;
```

Помимо этого, для каждой определённой серии/модели станка имеется своя версия заголовочного файла, содержимое которых различается значением и наличием некоторых констант препроцессора (могу ошибаться в терминах).

Для подключения к CNC, на данный момент, используется примерно такой код:

##### Интерфейс `Fwlib64Library`

```java
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLong;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.ShortByReference;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.NativeLongByReference;

public interface Fwlib64Library extends Library
{
    static final Fwlib64Library INSTANCE = Native.load( "Fwlib64", Fwlib64Library.class );

    short cnc_allclibhndl3( String host, short port, NativeLong timeout, ShortByReference libHandle );

    short cnc_freelibhndl( short libHandle );

    short cnc_alarm2( short libHandle,  NativeLongByReference alarm );

    short cnc_statinfo( short libHandle, ODBST statInfo );
}
```

##### Класс `ODBST`

```java
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.Structure.FieldOrder;

@FieldOrder({ "hdck", "tmmode", "aut", "run", "motion", "mstb", "emergency", "alarm", "edit" })
public class ODBST extends Structure
{
    public short    hdck;
    public short    tmmode;
    public short    aut;
    public short    run;
    public short    motion;
    public short    mstb;
    public short    emergency;
    public short    alarm;
    public short    edit;

    public ODBST() { super(); }

    public ODBST( short hdck, short tmmode, short aut, short run, short motion, short mstb, short emergency, short alarm, short edit )
    {
        super();
        this.hdck = hdck;
        this.tmmode = tmmode;
        this.aut = aut;
        this.run = run;
        this.motion = motion;
        this.mstb = mstb;
        this.emergency = emergency;
        this.alarm = alarm;
        this.edit = edit;
    }

    public ODBST( Pointer peer ) { super( peer ); }

    public static class ByReference extends ODBST implements Structure.ByReference { }

    public static class ByValue extends ODBST implements Structure.ByValue { }
}
```

##### Пример использования

```java
// зависимая библиотека Fwlibe64.dll необходимая для TCP/IP соединений,
// которую необходимо "подгрузить" для исключения ошибки EW_NODLL(-15)
Fwlibe64Library fwlibe = Fwlibe64Library.INSTANCE;

Fwlib64Library lib = Fwlib64Library.INSTANCE;
String host = "42.cnc.loc";
short port = 8193;
NativeLong timeout = new NativeLong( 10, true );
final ShortByReference libHandle = new ShortByReference();

final short connectionRetCode = lib.cnc_allclibhndl3( host, port, timeout, libHandle );

if( connectionRetCode == 0 && libHandle.getValue() != 0 )
{
    ODBST outStatInfo = new ODBST();
    lib.cnc_statinfo( libHandle.getValue(), outStatInfo );

    boolean isStop = outStatInfo.run == 1;
    boolean isHold = outStatInfo.run == 2;
    boolean isRun = outStatInfo.run == 3;

    short freeLibHandleRetCode = lib.cnc_freelibhndl( libHandle.getValue() );
}
```

---

Так как тип параметра *(в конкретном случае `ODBST statinfo` в функции `cnc_statinfo`)* должен различаться в зависимости от типа/версии используемой библиотеки Fwlib64.dll/заголовочного файла, то отсюда можно сделать вывод, что для каждой модели/серии CNC необходимо создавать отдельную JNA-обёртку/сборку *(к примеру `fwlib64-30i-1.0.0.jar`, `fwlib64-pmia-1.0.0.jar`, и т.д.)*, или я не прав и здесь есть какие-то дополнительные варианты?

Также, хотя в коде есть различия, всё таки большинство кода/типов/методов являются одинаковыми и вполне резонно хотелось бы не повторять/копировать этот код из одной JNA-обёртки в другую и по этому поводу имеются следующие варианты (пока покрытые мраком):

1. **Использовать различные Git ветки**
   К примеру ветку с основным кодом и для каждой серии CNC отдельную, а при релизе/сборке/публикации всё это каким это образом сливать/собирать с помощью Maven/GitLab.
2. **Использовать разные пакеты/пространства имён**
   Для каждой модели/версии назначить свой пакет *(например `fwlib64.series15`, `fwlib64.series_pmi` и т.д.)* и опять-же собирать различные сборки с помощью Maven/GitLab.

---

#### Вопрос

**Каким образом создать несколько сборок JNA-обёрток с определённой кодовой базой/пакетами/ветками с помощью Maven и GitLab?**

Comment: Используйте несколько проектов. По проекту на каждый вариант + проект с общим кодом + инфраструктурные. Ну и стоит рассмотреть вариант использовать JNI вместо JNA.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Вариант с несколькими проектами рассматривался первым, но как, при таком подходе, гарантировать, что при сборке новой версии все зависимые проекты будут также пересобраны? JNI не рассматривался по причине не критичности к скорости работы, а также из-за огромного количества нативных методов, для которых , в случае использования JNI, пришлось бы создавать и компилировать библиотеки для каждой целевой платформы.